# Count values where first character is alpha in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following column:

```
129302
;;;;
A.T.P.
Hi@gmail.com
Peter
'-
?
Hi
```

I need to know the amount of values that start with a letter character (a-z / A-Z), meaning the outcome should be 4.

I know I can use the following code to count the amount of values starting specifically with an 'M'.

```
Count = 
COUNTROWS ( 
    FILTER ( 
        'Table' , 
        LEFT ( 'Table'[column B] , 1 ) = "M" )
    )
)
```

How do I make the above more generic so that it will search for any a-z character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAX isn't case-sensitive, so you can use simply:

```
=
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        LEFT ( 'Table'[column B], 1 )
            IN {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"}
    )
)
```